# Why does a ClassNotFoundException für HandlerWrapper occur when migrating to Spring Boot 3.1.3?

Tags: spring-boot, jetty

I am currently migrating a Spring Boot application from 2.7.9 to 3.1.3.
I know that Jetty is not compatible with Spring Boot's servlet-api 6.0.0 until version 11.x, hence I decided to use jetty-server version 12.0.1 which promised to be compatible.
Unfortunately I get an exception that spring Boot is not able to instantiate a bean of `JettyServletWebServerFactory` due to lack of class `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper` what results in a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper`.

Why and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Jetty 12 contains many breaking API changes making it incompatible with Spring Boot 3.1. Jetty 12 will [hopefully be supported in Spring Boot 3.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36073). Until then, you cannot use Jetty 12 with Spring Boot.

Rather than trying to upgrade Jetty to 12, a better option is to downgrade the Servlet API dependency to 5.0. Exactly how you do that depends on the build system that you're using. There are some suggestions described in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33044).